# Regarding maximum attained on the boundary of a compact set

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, compactness

Let $K$ be a compact set in $\mathbb{C}$. Is it true that there exists an element of maximum modulus in $K$ and that element belongs to the boundary of $K$. If yes, how?

Comment: the function $|z|$ is continuous on a compact so by elementary topology it attains its maximum om $K$; now every interior point has an open disc around it included in $K$ and there you can find elements of higher modulus than the center (think geometrically and connect the center with the origin and take points inside the disc on that line but away from the origin - in other words, the disc center is collinear with but in between the origin and the point you take)

Comment: How are the two statements
I: the function $|z|$
 is continuous on a compact so by elementary topology it attains its maximum on $$.
II:  now every interior point has an open disc around it included in $$
 and there you can find elements of higher modulus than the center.

related?

Comment: The first statement shows that the maximum modulus is indeed attained on $K$ (topology) the second that it must be attained on a boundary point of $K$ (geometry) - for example the same problem with minimum modulus still is attained on $K$ by topology but it definitely can be interior since now there is no geometric reason to be boundary